# C# Entity Framework Core: Processing of the LINQ expression failed

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq

### The situation

We have the following tables in our MySQL database:

Table club (There are more columns but we only care about the Id for now):

```
Id | ...
---+----
1  | ...
```

Table genre:

```
Id | GenreName
---+-----------
1  | Rock
2  | Classic
3  | Techno
```

And table club2genre:

```
ClubId | GenreId
-------+--------
1      | 1
1      | 2
1      | 3
```

### The MySQL query

Using the following MySQL query:

```sql
SELECT
    club.Id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(genre.GenreName) as Music
FROM
    club
INNER JOIN club2genre
    ON club2genre.clubid = club.id
INNER JOIN genre
    ON genre.id = club2genre.genreid
GROUP BY
    club.Id;
```

we get (as expected) this result:

```
Id | Music
---+---------
1  | Rock,Classic,Techno
```

### The (buggy) C# LINQ expression in question

```
var queryResult = DbContext.Club.Join(
        DbContext.Club2Genre,
        club => club.Id,
        club2genre => club2genre.ClubId,
        (club, cg) => new
        {
            Id = club.Id,
            GenreId = cg.GenreId
        })
    .GroupJoin(
        DbContext.Genre,
        temp => temp.GenreId,
        genre => genre.Id,
        (temp, genreList) => new
        {
            ClubId = temp.Id,
            Genres = genreList.Select(genre => genre.Name)
        })
    .GroupBy(result => result.ClubId);

var result = result.ToList();
```

In theory this Entity Framework Core LINQ expression should be a 1:1 translation of the MySQL query above  where the result column that is aliased as `Music` (the `GROUP_CONCAT` one) should be an IEnumerablehowever upon execution the following exception is thrown:

[image: error]

Interestingly enough it only fails upon calling `ToList()` on the `queryResult` so I'm not even sure the LINQ expression itself is the problem. And (at least for me) the error message doesn't seem to be especially helpful other than essentially saying `"EF Core might be buggy but also maybe not. Who knows"`.

So my questions are:

**1.) Is what I'm trying to do even possible using LINQ and EF Core?**

**2.) If so, what is wrong my code and why does it crash?**

**3.) How do I fix it?**

Comment: GroupJoin is just not supported, see this issue: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/17068#issuecomment-586464350

Comment: Ooof :/ Well I guess that explains why it doesn't work. Is there a *supported *alternative though?

Comment: I personally not aware of any. As I remember, even `String.Join` is not supported in EF Core, but maybe specific provider you use supports it...

Comment: Alright guess I'll have to split my query up into multiple sub queries and do the group joining logic in c# then. Thank you for looking into it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an extension function, you can generate a `LEFT JOIN` and create a flattened result that can then be grouped on the client side to emulate the `GroupJoin`.

I assume that a single query that returns multiple copies of the left hand side is preferable to multiple queries splitting the left and right side, as that is what LINQ to SQL does, but it is also possible to implement a translation that does two queries, one for the left side, and one for the right side where it matches the left side, then join on the client. This eliminates the duplicate left hand side at the expense of two queries. You can also minimize the left duplication and network traffic by putting in `Select`s that narrows each side down to only the columns needed for the keys and the result.

```
public static class QueryableExt {
    // implement GroupJoin for EF Core 3 by using `LEFT JOIN` and grouping on client side
    public static IEnumerable<TRes> GroupJoinEF<TLeft,TRight,TKey,TRes>(
        this IQueryable<TLeft> leftq,
             IQueryable<TRight> rightq,
             Expression<Func<TLeft,TKey>> leftKeyExp,
             Expression<Func<TRight,TKey>> rightKeyExp,
             Func<TLeft, IEnumerable<TRight>, TRes> resFn) =>

        leftq.GroupJoin(rightq, leftKeyExp, rightKeyExp, (left, rightj) => new { left, rightj })
             .SelectMany(lrj => lrj.rightj.DefaultIfEmpty(), (lrj, right) => new { lrj.left, right })
             .AsEnumerable()
             .GroupBy(lr => lr.left, lr => lr.right, (left, rightg) => resFn(left, rightg));
}
```

With this extension, your query becomes:

```
var queryResult = DbContext.Club
                    .GroupJoinEF(DbContext.Club2Genre.Join(DbContext.Genre, c2g => c2g.GenreId, g => g.Id, (c2g, g) => new { c2g.Id, g.Genre }),
                         c => c.Id,
                         cg => cg.Id,
                         (c, cgj) => new {
                             c.Id,
                             Music = String.Join(",", cgj.Select(cg => cg?.Genre))
                         }
                    );
```

However, since you aren't using `LEFT JOIN` in your query, you don't need a full `GroupJoin` implementation, and could just use `Join` and again, group on the client side:

```
var queryResult = DbContext.Club
                    .Join(DbContext.Club2Genre, c => c.Id, c2g => c2g.Id, (c, c2g) => new { c.Id, c2g.GenreId })
                    .Join(DbContext.Genre, cgi => cgi.GenreId, g => g.Id, (cgi, g) => new { cgi.Id, g.Genre })
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .GroupBy(cg => cg.Id, (cId, cgg) => new { Id = cId, Music = String.Join(",", cgg.Select(cg => cg.Genre)) });
```